# Making jquery fullcalendar printer friendly?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I want to be able to print out my jquery fullcalendar along with events; however, it comes out very hard to read and obviously the background colors are not coming out. Is there a way to make it print in a clearer way maybe with bolder colors, a solid background, or no through lines from the hour marks?

**UPDATE:** 
In the "agendaWeek" format (what is specifically need) it looks absolutely terrible  - the events seem to span over more than one day - even though the calendar (kind of) fits into the page. This means that Wednesday events and onwards are "off the chart" so to speak...

[**SAMPLE PRINT VIEW**](http://img31.imageshack.us/img31/8441/databasew.jpg)

Comment: did you include <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media="print" href='fullcalendar.print.css' /> in your page?! It works fine for me and the printed page doesn't have any styling at all. If you're not content with the look of it I suggest adding some stuff in the fullcalendar.print.css to make it look prettier.

Comment: thanks.yes - i dont have the print css in place. the problem is that the events are all out of their day column. its not a matter of styling - the positioning is all off.

Comment: When I try to print *without* the print css my calendar get split into two pages, with the css it looks fine. Isn't it possible to use the print css to make the events thinner so that they fit into your day slots?

Comment: sure, i guess i could try play with it, i just assume that the print.cc file was supposed to do that on its own already ;)

Comment: Life is seldom that easy.. Unfortionatly...

Answer (score 7):

Check your downloaded .zip-file from http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/download/
It includes a printer friendly css and in it instructions on how to use it.

Good luck!

Comment: ok - i need to re-open this question - i have added some clarification in my question.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The newest fullcalendar (3.0) should allow you to print with the spacing between events intact now. No need to use the fullcalendar.print.css file.